# Change color of cell based on value out of array iOS

Tags: ios, xcode

Any idea what's wrong with this:

```
 if ([status isEqualToString: @"green"])
     [[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 200 green: 191 blue: 231 alpha: 1]];
```

I defined the array in the @implementation. Xcode shows the following error:

> no visible `@interface` for `NSArray` declares the selector `isEqualToString:`.

The idea is that the cell background becomes green when the string value in the array is equal to the string "green" (values in the `colorWithRed` are not the actual color green)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: is 'status' your array? From outside I have a feeling that you are comparing an array against a string.

Comment: An array shouldn't be compared to string directly. You can use `if ([status[0] isEqualToString: @"green"])` if that is what you want.

Comment: THNX ACB yes you are right only have to compare the value at the index  with the string not the whole array. Do i need to use a for loop every time to check the the value for the cell. This allows me to change the color of the cell. I had the feeling that the cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath takes care of that. probably a trivial question. sorry for that.

Answer (score 4):

Problem is in RGB value.

in normal RGB are between 0 to 255

But

```
+ (UIColor *)colorWithRed:(CGFloat)red green:(CGFloat)green blue:(CGFloat)blue alpha:(CGFloat)alpha
```

take value between 0.0 to 1.0

So u can do like this:

```
[[cell contentView] setBackgroundColor: [UIColor colorWithRed: 200.0/255.0 
                                                        green: 191.0/255.0 
                                                         blue: 231.0/255.0 
                                                         alpha: 1]];
```

Have a look here [colorWithRed:green:blue:alpha:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIColor_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/UIColor/colorWithRed%3agreen%3ablue%3aalpha%3a)

Comment: you should use 200.0/255, 191.0/255 and 231.0/255 to transform values to float type or they will all be 0

Answer (score 1):

It appears that `status` is an `NSArray` you cannot compare that to a string especially using isEqualToString. Try using something like `[status objectAtIndex:0];` or changing `status` to an `NSString`

Also CRDave is correct you should be dividing all of your color numbers by 255. Well they are CGFloats I believe so technically 255.0 otherwise the number will be rounded and result in 0 (or 1) everytime.

If you want an actual green color you can also just use `[UIColor greenColor];` (unless however you want a specific green color)