# UIView background colour white

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, uicolor

I have the following code within my table view controller. It returns a custom view for section headers in the table.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    UIView *header = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 30)];

    if (tableView == contentTable && section == 0) {
        // When I set backgroundColor to [UIColor redColor] it works. Otherwise white.
        [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.f green:12.f blue:88.f alpha:1.f]];
    } else {
        [header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    }

    return header;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == contentTable && section == 0) {
        return 30;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now this code works fine, however the view returned is White. If I ever set the `backgroundColor` to `[UIColor redColor]` for example it will turn red. However if I set a custom RGB value it will just stay white. I used RGB values from within photoshop.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14612638/change-color-of-cell-based-on-value-out-of-array-ios/14612987#14612987

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The RGB values are floats whose range must be between `0.0f` and `1.0f`. If you want to convert from 0-255 values, divide each value by `255.0f`.

Answer (score 0):

```
[header setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:10.0f/255.0 green:12.0f/255.0 blue:88.0f/255.0 alpha:1.f]];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the color values from Photoshop, you can use like

```
[UIColor colorWithRed:10.f/255.0f green:12.f/255.0f blue:88.f/255.0f alpha:1.0f]];
```

This is the way I use.

Enjoy yourself!